# MySQL 5.7 - Increment a number in JSON

Tags: mysql, sql

Is it possible to mass increment a specific JSON attribute?

For example, my JSON column is called `metadata` and looks like this:

```
{"counter": 0, ...}
```

Can I update multiple rows so that the counter increments by 1 with a single query?

Edit:

Since this is getting flagged for too broad, let me give an exact example.

Data on table `x`, the only column on it is `metadata` and it has 3 rows:

`{"counter": 0}`, `{"counter": 1}`, `{"counter": 0, "something": "somethign"}`

Desired result is one query that would update those 3 to this:

`{"counter": 1}`, `{"counter": 2}`, `{"counter": 1, "something": "somethign"}`

It goes without saying that I'm not an expert with MySQL and I didn't manage to get together a query that would work for me from the MySQL documentation. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you read through the MySQL docs on JSON types and read how to modify values? http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/

Comment: Yeah. Looks like https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-modification-functions.html might have what you need. I would think you could accomplish with JSON_SET or JSON_REPLACE. But I haven't used it before.

Comment: Yeah I'll definitely need something in the MySQL manual. `JSON_SET` and `JSON_REPLACE` could both probably work. But how do I reference previous value and increment it by 1, while leaving other columns untouched? I mean every single SO question can be answered by a half-arsed "have you read x". Mine is pretty specific and I didn't find it answered yet

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use `JSON_EXTRACT` along with `JSON_SET`:

```
UPDATE table SET col = JSON_SET(col, '$.counter', JSON_EXTRACT(col, '$.counter') + 1)
```